# How to change Label position using Auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, uilabel

I have two label side by side "Label 1" and "Label 2". If "Label 1" content is not available then "Label 2" replace "Label 1" position. Do any one know how is it possible using auto layout?[image]

For trying purpose, I have fixed height and weight for both Labels. "Label 1" have leading and Top 8 pixel margin, while "Label 2" have 0 pixel for leading and 8 pixel for Top. Set "Label 1" size to "0", Hide "Label 1" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Take `IBOutlet` of `Label 2 width` and set its `constant` value accordingly.

Comment: you can do it using outlets .. just make  width constraint outlet and if label 1 empty then set its constant  to 0

Comment: Do you need the big, fixed width? Or do you want the labels to auto-size to fit the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove width constraint for both labels and update (set) compression/hugging priority for labels according to your requirement (from size inspector).

By removing width constraint your problem will be resolved, but autoLayout may show conflict for content display priority because of, your both labels are positioned, horizontally in a same line (points). To resolve this conflict, you need to update compression/hugging priority of any one of both labels.

Now, when there is no value for any one (or both) label text, set nil value for it, so its frame (space) will be automatically occupied by other label. And if both label text has nil value then both will be disappeared (automatically set their width to zero).

[image]

Comment: I have followed your steps but it doesn't show me conflicts.

Comment: Did you set leading constaint for label 1?    Does your problem solved, or still facing this issue.  By removing width, your problem will be resolved. just set nil value for label text, when you don't want to display label.

Answer (score 1):

If both the labels have fixed width , set constant width to both the labels. Set Lable2 leading space is '0' with respect to label1. Add a `NSLayoutConstraint` to the Label1 width. Now programatically when you found that Lable1 content is blank, set its width layout constraint to '0'. Lable2 will be automatically moved left and sits in the place of Label1.

Comment: "set constant width to both the labels" it means equal width for both labels?

Comment: That is based on your requirement. If your label going to hold fixed length of string, set constant width value. if label going to hold variable / dynamic length of string, set width value in proportion. But I recommend to go with Krunal answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `IBOutlet` of width constraint of Label2 and you need to check for content of Label1. If you found it blank then you need to set with to zero and call `layoutIfNeeded` to reset view frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to work with compression/hugging properties. Then you can embed labels inside stackview and hide label when there is no content.

[image]

And when I hide label1

[image]

No constraints required :)